# Remove class from closest class when clicked on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    $(".hnf-link").click(function () {
        if ($('.hnf-menu').hasClass('hnf-menu--hidden')) {
            $(".hnf-menu").removeClass('hnf-menu--hidden').addClass('hnf-menu--level2open');
        } else {
            $(".hnf-menu").removeClass('hnf-menu--level2open').addClass('hnf-menu--hidden');
        }
    });
    
    
    //PROBLEM STARTS HERE
    
        $(".hnf-link2").click(function () {
        if ($('.hnf-menu__nav3').hasClass('hnf-menu__nav3--hidden')) {
            $(".hnf-menu__nav3.hnf-menu__nav3--hidden").closest("li").find(".hnf-menu__nav3.hnf-menu__nav3--hidden").removeClass('hnf-menu__nav3--hidden');
            $(".hnf-menu--level2open").addClass('hnf-menu-wide');

        }
    });
```

```css
  .hnf-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 8000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 200ms 0s;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform, visibility;
  }

  .hnf-menu {
    transition-property: transform, visibility, width;
    width: 30rem;
    right: auto;
  }

  .hnf-menu--hidden {
    transform: translateX(-470px);
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .hnf-menu__container--default .hnf-menu__nav3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
  }

  .hnf-menu__container--default .hnf-menu__nav3 {
    left: 305px;
    width: 320px;
    padding-top: 2.5rem;


  }

  .hnf-menu-wide {
    width: 50rem;
  }

  .hnf-menu__nav3.hnf-menu__nav3--hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  a {
    display:block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="hnf-header__nav__main">
    <li>
        <a class="hnf-link" href="#">Products</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<aside class="hnf-menu hnf-menu--default hnf-menu--hidden">
    <div class="hnf-menu__container hnf-menu__container--default">
        <nav class="hnf-menu__nav2">
            <ul class="hnf-menu__nav2__main">
                <!-- Category 1 -->
                <li>
                    <a class="hnf-link2" href="#">Category 1</a>
                    <nav class="hnf-menu__nav3 hnf-menu__nav3--hidden">
                        <ul class="hnf-menu__nav3__main">
                            <li>
                                <a class="hnf-link" href="#">Subcateeegory 1.1</a>
                                <a class="hnf-link" href="#">Subcateeegory 1.2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </li>
                <!-- Category 2 -->
                <li>
                    <a class="hnf-link2" href="#">Category 2</a>
                    <nav class="hnf-menu__nav3 hnf-menu__nav3--hidden">
                        <ul class="hnf-menu__nav3__main">
                            <li>
                                <a class="hnf-link" href="#">Subcategory 2.1</a>
                                <a class="hnf-link" href="#">Subcategory 2.2</a>
                                <a class="hnf-link" href="#">Subcategory 2.3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</aside>
```

I'm having porblems removing the *closest* class `.hnf-menu__nav3--hidden` when clicked on the link with class `.hnf-link2`.

Fiddle of my problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/c6gdh821/4/

As you can see, I need to remove the class `.hnf-menu__nav3--hidden` from the "Category 1" block if clicked on the link "Category 1" and from the "Category 2" block if clicked on the link "Category 2", so that it will show **only** the corresponding subcategories and not all.

Thanks

Comment: _"Fiddle of my problem"_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] **in the question itself**

Comment: What "rules"? o.O The tooltip of the DV button: _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"_ - Without a [mcve] _in the question itself_ it is unclear and not useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not focusing on the element which is clicked. You may refer jQuery `$(this)`. I found a tutorial here https://www.yogihosting.com/jquery-this/.

Modifying the code like below will fix your issue;

```
$(".hnf-link2").click(function () {
    $(".hnf-menu__nav3").addClass('hnf-menu__nav3--hidden');
    $(this).closest("li").find(".hnf-menu__nav3.hnf-menu__nav3--hidden").removeClass('hnf-menu__nav3--hidden');
    $(".hnf-menu--level2open").addClass('hnf-menu-wide');
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8new2q0g/

The code basically assigns hidden class to all `hnf-menu__nav3` selectors and removes the hidden class from the closest selector.

Comment: Awesome, thx. I really need to go through this tutorial.